# Can I str_replace in another file?

Tags: php, str-replace

I am working on a file that should replace a variable in another file. So far I tried:

```
$File = "$dir/submit.php";
$fh = fopen($File, 'r') or die("Couldn't edit the Config-file. Please report to admin.");
$chosendb = str_replace('$chosendb = comments;','$chosendb = wuhuws_$dir;','$chosendb');
fclose($fh);
```

$dir is a user input.
comments is a table in the database that need to replaced with the prefix_$dir.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You haven't even read from the file. You merely opened a handle to it.  [Use `file_get_contents()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read it into a string.  However, see @zerkms this not being a good idea to begin with...

Comment: @bfavaretto: argh!!! ;-)

Comment: @Christian: you better explain **why** you need that

Comment: @Christian Because it's impossible to debug for one. Your stacktraces becoming meaningless when your source can change like that. If you want to change source files based on actions performed on the website you might-as-well render full html pages and `str_replace()` those every time something on the page needs to be updated.

Comment: How does your so called config file look like? Perhaps it is better to include it, "read" data this way and then process the changes.

Comment: @zerkms I sit with a small app that based on a user input in a form $dir will create a folder, copy some template files and create a table in the database. I just need the copied template file to change the database table (MySQL) from where it gets the comments etc.

MikeB I made it so that the process will be stopped if the folder is already existing - does that make it better? The process will only be able to be executed once.

Comment: @djot Good comment. The Config-file is simply the one I try to open :)

Comment: Config files shouldn't be .php - use ini and `parse_ini_file()`. A database-name change shouldn't require editing of your source.

Comment: @Christian Then I see no reason why you cannot `include()` it and then change the variables normally :-)?

Comment: @Christian I mean, if you would have an array in your config file, why not just include(file.php) and make changes "on the fly" without the need to replace text.

Comment: @Christian, from your description, you could have implemented that without creating new tables, just by having an additional row on existing tables with the value of `$dir`. Then filter the data according to the current context (`$dir`) on your `SELECT` queries.

Comment: @Zar It's simply because I am a complete PHP-noob. I code to learn and to play and well - I end up facing these walls of codes where I can only try :P What is "change the variables normally?"

Comment: @Mike B  Why not .php? Why should .ini be better? It's pretty much the same, but .php won't show in the browser.

Comment: @djot I need the thing automated. Sorry if that's what you mean. I really have to concentrate to keep up :P

Comment: @djot Neither should .ini if you have apache configured correctly (if you have your config files in your DOCUMENT_ROOT then you have more problems then what file-format to choose for configuration). Because .php files are source files and shouldn't change. There are file-formats and parsing engines written specifically for configuration data.. .ini is one of them. Yaml is another popular format. It's easy to drill down into a certain configuration item, edit it, then write it back to the file without a problem. Doing the same thing in a .php file is tricky (see this question)

Comment: @bfavaretto I need a complete table with the current settings. It's also doing something with users and comments and stuff :) Which works. Right now it basically creates a new "room" but calls the first "rooms" chat/comments

Comment: @Christian simply including it and then `$foo = "bar"` is enough. You see, when you include a PHP file, the current script "inherites" all the variables from the included file. Hence, a variable from the included file can be accessed and therefore modified in the running script.

Comment: @Zar I guess it answers my question below. So if I include it and then sets the variable as I would if it was a single file - it would work?

Comment: @Christian okay, just keep in mind what we are trying to say here: avoid self-modifying PHP code, it's a bad practice!

Comment: The PHP-process is made with a single file :) I don't think I mentioned it. Or if it's important.

Comment: @bfavaretto I will. That's why I came here in the first place :) I know a lot about front end and basic PHP. But I come here to learn and you learn't me that. I will find another practice than self-modifying.

Comment: @Mike B Well, I don't need any files myself ;)

Comment: Thank you everyone for their help. @Zar - espcially you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting to write to the file again.

```
// Read the file
$content = file_get_contents("$dir/submit.php");

// Do the editing
$content = str_replace('$chosendb = comments;','$chosendb = wuhuws_$dir;', $content);

// Save the file
file_put_contents("$dir/submit.php", $content);
```

However, as Zerkms said (*or atleast intended to ;-)* ), it's generally a **bad idea** to edit PHP with PHP, especially since you'll find a hard time debugging your script later since its code dynamically changes upon runtime.

Is there any reason why you cannot include this file and manually set these variables, like:

```
// Include the file    
require("$dir/submit.php"); 
// Edit the variable
$chosendb = "wuhuws_$dir";
```

Comment: I could manually set it - but the users should be able to automatically create a room themselves. Room = the process. :)

What you did in the end of your answer - how does it do what I want? :) I just need it explained.